# What to use for logic control circuit without Programming?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, control

I need to design a digital combinational logic circuit for control a small scale industrial product which normally uses mechanical relays.  There are only few LEDs as indicator and few digital output to trigger actuators. It is very simple task with Arduino or other microcontrollers but company doesn't want any programming. I did it with logic gates but also looking for alternatives for more scalable solution.

working principle is as following:

There are main switch, door switch, temperatur sensors, pressure sensors, motors and indicators.

When door is open, motors should start. This is done with trigger signal to motor controller. Necdessary conditions are: main switch is on, temperature is in range, pressure is in range and door is open.

Another function is to heat up blowing air. This is done with cable. Switches cut or conenct main power. Here alsopre-conditons are same.

Indicator lights shows if motors are working or not. If there is overpressure or not, if temperature is too cold or not.

Sensors are also just a simple on/off switch,

[Here is the basic system. This solution is tested and works well but better way could be](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2050%205%2043%0As%20-16%20112%2016%20112%200%200%20false%0AI%2048%20112%2080%20112%200%200.5%205%0Aw%2016%20112%2048%20112%202%0As%20-16%20240%2016%20240%200%200%20false%0Aw%2016%20240%2048%20240%200%0Aw%2048%20240%2048%20304%200%0Aw%2048%20304%20160%20304%203%0AI%20160%20304%20192%20304%200%200.5%205%0Aw%20192%20304%20224%20304%200%0As%20240%20160%20288%20160%200%200%20false%0As%20304%20160%20352%20160%200%200%20false%0Aw%20304%20160%20288%20160%202%0Aw%20224%20272%20240%20272%200%0Aw%20224%20304%20240%20304%200%0Aw%20304%20288%20368%20288%200%0Ar%20416%20160%20448%20160%200%201000%0A162%20480%20160%20512%20160%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20448%20160%20480%20160%203%0AI%20352%20160%20400%20160%200%200.5%205%0Aw%20400%20160%20416%20160%200%0Aw%2048%20240%20368%20240%200%0Aw%20352%20160%20352%20224%200%0Aw%20352%20224%20368%20224%200%0A150%20400%20240%20448%20240%200%203%205%205%0Aw%20368%20224%20400%20224%202%0Aw%20368%20240%20400%20240%202%0Aw%20368%20288%20368%20256%200%0Aw%20368%20256%20400%20256%202%0Ar%20464%20240%20496%20240%200%201000%0Aw%20448%20240%20464%20240%202%0A162%20512%20240%20544%20240%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Ag%20560%20240%20560%20288%200%0Aw%20544%20240%20560%20240%200%0Aw%20512%20240%20496%20240%200%0Aw%2048%20240%2048%20160%200%0Aw%2048%20160%2096%20160%200%0Aw%2096%20160%20112%20160%200%0Aw%2080%20112%2080%20128%200%0Aw%2080%20128%20144%20128%202%0Aw%20144%20128%20160%20128%200%0Aw%20144%20160%20160%20160%200%0Aw%20176%20144%20208%20144%200%0Aw%20208%20144%20208%2048%203%0Ar%20208%2048%20240%2048%200%201000%0A162%20256%2048%20288%2048%202%20default-led%201%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20256%2048%20240%2048%200%0Aw%2048%20352%20304%20352%202%0Aw%2048%20352%2048%20304%200%0Aw%20304%20288%20304%20336%200%0Aw%20304%20336%20320%20336%200%0Aw%20304%20352%20320%20352%200%0A150%20352%20352%20384%20352%200%202%205%205%0Aw%20320%20336%20352%20336%202%0Aw%20320%20352%20320%20368%200%0Aw%20320%20368%20352%20368%200%0Aw%20384%20352%20400%20352%200%0Aw%20400%20352%20416%20352%200%0Aw%20416%20352%20416%20304%200%0Aw%20416%20304%20336%20304%200%0Aw%20336%20304%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20336%20192%20240%20192%200%0Aw%20240%20192%20240%20160%200%0AR%20-160%20160%20-160%2096%200%200%2040%2024%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20-48%20160%20-16%20160%200%0Aw%20-16%20160%20-16%20112%200%0Aw%20-16%20160%20-16%20240%200%0Aw%2016%20112%2016%20144%200%0Aw%2016%20144%2064%20144%200%0Aw%2064%20144%2064%20272%200%0Aw%2064%20272%20224%20272%203%0A152%20256%20288%20288%20288%200%202%205%205%0Aw%20240%20272%20256%20272%200%0Aw%20240%20304%20256%20304%200%0Aw%20304%20288%20288%20288%200%0A150%20160%20144%20176%20144%200%202%200%205%0Aw%20112%20160%20144%20160%202%0Aw%20288%2048%20560%2048%200%0Aw%20560%2048%20560%20240%200%0Aw%20512%20160%20560%2048%200%0Ar%20-48%20176%20-48%20208%200%201000%0Ar%20-144%20160%20-112%20160%200%201000%0Aw%20-112%20160%20-48%20160%200%0Aw%20-160%20160%20-144%20160%200%0Aw%20-)

On the photo, it is the other system.

[image: Here is the complex system. Not sure if it works and pretty sure that there is another way to simplify this without any programming and microcontroller]

Comment: your answer is WAAAY to abstract. Show us a schematic of your solution, at least rough schematic. A picture. Show us how it works and we may suggest something based on it. Your description is pretty vague otherwise.

Comment: thanks for comment. I have edited the post for better understanding

Comment: A PLC with some graphical programming enviroment?

Comment: Why exactly can't you use a MCU? Too simple? Too cheap BOM cost? I suppose you could use some manner of old school "PLD" in VHDL, but that's just another form of (more expensive) programming.

Comment: because there is no one except me who understands programming. Normally when there is a problem they just simply change the relays.  plc is expensive for our units. so, now alternative is just changing the pcb. Therefore, boss doesn't want to come to 21.century and prefers something doesn't need programming although design is still only depending on me. It is hard to convince old school people. It takes time.

Comment: @bcicek Microcontrollers started to replace digital logic in the 1980s. They aren't refusing to come to the 21th century, they are refusing to come into the 1980s... Besides, finding someone with basic C skill who can program a bit of boolean logic isn't hard. Anyone going through an EE degree today has taken at least one beginner class in C programming.

Comment: @Lundin ok, i was a bit optimistic :) that's what i said to boss as well but their choice.. They always find the most none sense way. Regarding cost also, it is stupid to invent electronic from beginning but nothing to do.Tesla is crying on grave now.

Answer (score 2):

Your bosses are not as out of touch as it would seem. Using a software approach to automation always has an issue: it’s not self-documenting, at least, not in the way that a logic or relay diagram is. This makes the system more difficult to analyze.

A Silego Greenpak could do this logic-oriented approach, for very cheap. It uses LUTs to implement gates so you could render the logic more or less directly. Uses a GUI for design entry, dev environment is very affordable. And it’s self-documenting.

More conventional ways to implement logic include a CPLD or an FPGA. You need to ‘program’ these using some kind of hardware description language like Verilog, but you could express your gate logic directly as your coding style and extract a schematic from that for your bosses to look at.

Really though this sounds like a job for a PLC, which solves a bunch of other problems too, like I/O conditioning. There are GUI front-ends for them that avoid ‘coding’ per se that model the kinds of behaviors that relays implement, so they are self-documenting to an extent (the very reason for ‘ladder logic’ is to solve that conundrum, making it possible for non-programmers to understand what is supposed to happen.)

Here’s a whole bunch of cheap PLCs, some under $50. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/news/low-cost-programmable-logic-controllers-for-the-frugal-engineer/

And finally, PLC on Arduino is a thing. Worth a look.

Comment: Looking at BOM + assembly cost and assuming a bit of volume, some 100+ pcs, I'd say that roughly a MCU board is ~$20, a digital logic board ~$50 and a PLC ~$1000. One can chose desired unit price depending on the desired level of incompetence in the company. Except a PLC actually requires some manner of programming too...

Comment: And one can likely hire a engineering student to code the MCU logic for less than the price of one single PLC...

Comment: There are less expensive options for PLC now. See my revised answer. Nevertheless I’d not want that student designing the I/O - there’s a reason these things cost money.

Comment: Student meaning the cheapskate option. If you want to hire professionals to do the software + PCB, then it naturally gets far more expensive, but you get quality, it's a one time cost and you shave off a lot of cost from the recurring unit price.

Comment: @hack, most of the big PLC players, Siemens, A-B, Mitsubishi, etc., have micro PLCs for €100 or so with built-in LCD display - typically 4 or 6 x 20 characters - and can be programmed if stuck from the six-button keypad. They're brilliant and ideal for this job.

Comment: @Transistor, thanks for that. Agreed - buy makes much more sense than make, and you’ve amplified that point.